# Warn user if wrong value is not in the table (Mysql + C)

Tags: mysql, c

I have a table:

```
For_Sconti  |    Cat_Sconti    |  Sconto 

  7148               A1          451.00
```

How can I prevent the user from inserting a wrong (not in the table) For_Sconti value when
trying to update the Sconto field?

In a nutshell, through a C interface I'd like to update the above mentioned table.

```
do {
    printf("Insert For_Sconti: \n");
    scanf("%s", For_Sconti);
    }
    while (strlen(For_Sconti)>5);
```

Here I'd like to warn the user whenever he/she insert a For_Sconti value which is not in the table.

I thought about this:

```
strcat(query, "SELECT For_Sconti,Cat_Sconti FROM Sconti;");
result = mysql_store_result (conn);
mysql_field_seek (result, 0);         
row = mysql_fetch_row (result);
```

But I believe, it's just nonsense.

Can someone help me?

Comment: what you want is for `For_Sconti` to be a [foreign key](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp).

Comment: What I want is not preventing from inserting duplicates ..Actuallu the user should not insert a value which is not in the table...For_Sconti and Cat_Sconti are Foreign key

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [mysql_affected_rows()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-affected-rows.html) function. If result is 0, then user has tried to modify non-existent For_Sconti.

Comment: thanks ...I tried this but I can't go any further memset(query, 0, 200);
 strcat(query, "SELECT  For_Sconti FROM Sconti WHERE For_Sconti='");
 strcat(query,For_Sconti);
        strcat(query, "' AND Cat_Sconti='");
 strcat(query, Cat_Sconti);
 strcat(query, "';");
 strcat(query,"';");
 result = mysql_store_result (conn);

Comment: then once a I stored the query result how do I use the mysql_affected_rows() ?

Comment: Use this command just after the INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE command. It will say how many rows were affected.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps you have to follow:
1.- Get the For_Sconti value.
2.- Write a query like:
  sprintf(outString"SELECT %s FROM myTable",readValue);

3.- And then check the result to see if it contains something if it contains something then allow the user to insert a new value, else warn the user about the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Primary keys prevent duplication; foreign keys restrict the range of allowed values.

Assuming you have a foreign key constraint, you probably just want to try to insert the user-supplied data, and trap the error your C interface library returns when you violate a foreign key constraint. This method requires only one round-trip to the database.

If you want to know whether the user-supplied value exists in the database, execute a query like this one, and examine its return value.

```
SELECT (COUNT(*) > 0) as For_sconti_exists
FROM Sconti
WHERE For_sconti = <the user-supplied value>
```

This method requires two round-trips for valid values--one to determine whether the value exists, and one to insert the row.  You also have to

- pay attention to transaction isolation levels,
- execute both statements within a single transaction (or someone could delete the rows you think have valid values between the time you SELECT and the time you INSERT), and
- trap errors anyway.